# Navigation Bar logo title not centered

Tags: swift, navigation, uinavigationbar

I've implemented a logo as the navigation bar title, using the code below:

```
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 40))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        let image = UIImage(named: "nav_bar_icon_gradient.png")
        imageView.image = image

        self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

It works however the item is fully centred on the navigation bar (see screenshot), I'm aware it could be because of the navigation bar item on the right. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your code is fine. I think your icon has problems. Set `imageView` background color (`imageView.backgroundColor = .red`) to see if view is centered.